# Bash or Powershell scripting help needed

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, scripting, windows-7

I need to import a .csv file that has 2 columns and 40 rows of users and their computer name. Please look below for an example on how the workbook is setup.

Name Column

What I need from the script is to echo the users in the NAME column to a folder that would be name after their computer which this information is stored in the computername column for each user (so 40 times).

I tried coming up with a powershell line but is not working as expected.

Also tried using bash for this but having an issue computer name

But so far I am stuck here. Going to keep hammering at this but though maybe someone in the community could share their wisdom!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrMpG.png

```
$dataSource=import-csv "C:\temp\local_admin.csv"
foreach($dataRecord in $datasource) {
    $Name=$dataRecord.Name
    $CN=$dataRecord.CN
    echo $name > $CN.txt until end 
}
```

This is the bash line I was trying to get to work.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%X in ("c:\temp\local_admin.txt") do (echo %%X > 
c:\temp\test\%computername%.txt)
```

Comment: Just edit the question and paste the code in as best you can, if you can't get the formatting right someone with privileges may be able to help, but we can't if the code isn't available.

Comment: Please paste the code as text, not an image. I will help format the code if I can but I'm not going to transcribe it from an image!

Comment: Will try again! :)

Comment: I am such an idiot! But I figured it out. Sorry for being a potato...

Comment: That's ok, this is a good start. Some questions I have: 1) It's a bit unclear which columns exist in the CSV. Two columns? `Name` and `CN`? 2) what happens when you run your powershell? What is the result and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: 1) Name CN/ComputerName 
A_potato.me pme-l1 

2) If I run the script it gives no error and just runs. I try searching for the output but nothing is found on the machine. I tried changing the output file extension to narrow my search but nothing comes up. The result I am aiming for is for the script to output 40 .txt files each having the user name from column one and being named in a folder by their machine name (column b).

If I remove the > cn.txt the output shows all the 40 users. Which is awesome! But transfering that output to 40 different txt files is the issue I am facing.

Comment: Also, if I change the echo $name to echo $cn I get the 40 machine names as an output. So I feel I am close to my end result is just the second piece is what is killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you want, but this should get you close with Powershell:

```
$outDir = "C:\Temp\Output\"
$dataSource=import-csv "C:\temp\local_admin.csv"
foreach($dataRecord in $datasource) {
    $Name=$dataRecord.Name
    $CN=$dataRecord.CN
    $Name | Out-File $outDir$CN".txt"
}
```

This will output one file per row in the data source.  The file will be named as the computer name, and will contain the associated person's name within the file.  You should be able to adjust this as necessary to suit your needs.